# Firefox not showing applications in helper applications file manager

Tags: 18.04, firefox

When choosing an application to open file types and choosing "Use other...", the file manager that shows up does not show applications like transmission-gtk.

The which command outputted "/usr/bin/transmission-gtk"

[image: Helper Application not showing transmission-gtk]

Answer (score 0):

Using the firefox from mozillla's website instead of the one from ubuntu software fixed it.